# How to check if page is being iframed inside a colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have certain pages on my site that sometimes open in regular windows and sometimes open in an iframe inside colorbox modal windows (depending on location and context).

When a page is being displayed in an inframe inside a colorbox, I want to remove certain navigational elements from the page. To do this, first I need to find out, if the page is being displayed inside a colorbox.

Is there a way to find this out through jQuery?

Thanks.